# Grouping a list by proximity in value

Tags: list, python-2.7, group-by

How could I go about grouping a list of the form

((1156.0, 167, 78309.39), (1158.0, 168, 78322.731), (1156.0, 169, 65375.50), (34.0, 221, 64669.58), (34.0, 222, 91244.20), (35.0, 223, 90929.57), (34.0, 224, 90857.39))

into separate lists based on the first value in each nested list in Python.  I want lists beginning with values that are within a few number of each other to be grouped together, so the result would look like:
((1156.0,167,78309.39), (1158.0, 168, 78322.73), (1156.0, 169, 65375.50))

((34.0, 221, 64669.58), (34.0, 222, 91244.20), (35.0, 223, 90929.57), (34.0, 224, 90857.39))

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
x = ((1156.0, 167, 78309.39), (1158.0, 168, 78322.731), (1156.0, 169, 65375.50), (34.0, 221, 64669.58), (34.0, 222, 91244.20), (35.0, 223, 90929.57), (34.0, 224, 90857.39))
max_step = 10
result = []
prev = None
for y in sorted(x):
    if prev and y[0] - prev < max_step:
        result[-1].append(y)
    else:
        result.append([y])
        prev = y[0]
```